# I generated a constructor function for event Listener. But it is not working the way i want

Tags: javascript, onclick

I am creating a video toggle page using pure javascript. Whenever I click on the disable controls button. The controls should get disabled. And get enabled on clicking Enable Btn. I heard about the DRY principle. So to follow it completely. I created a constructor function for event Listener which should work after I a pass "element", "event", "action" parameters to it.

Initially, there were a lot of errors in my code. By, I improvised and made it work. The addEventListener is attached to the button and it gives me console log also. But the action is not getting executed. I don't know why. Kindly help. Thanks in advance.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge" />
    <title>Player</title>

    <style></style>

    <link
      rel="stylesheet"
      href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css"
      integrity="sha256-YLGeXaapI0/5IgZopewRJcFXomhRMlYYjugPLSyNjTY="
      crossorigin="anonymous"
    />

  </head>
  <body>
    <h2 class="text-warning text-center">
      Video Player DOM Manipulation Using using Pure JS
    </h2>
    <p class="text-center">I have used Dry Principle so that code is compact</p>
    <div class="container">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-6 mx-auto">
          <video
            class="mx-auto"
            src="video\your_video.mp4"
            width="500px"
            autoplay="true"
            controls
          ></video>
        </div>
      </div>

      <div class="row mb-5">
        <div class="col-md-6 mx-auto">
          <p class="text-warning font-weight-bold">Controls :-</p>
          <button class="btn btn-sm btn-success enableBtn">Enable</button>
          <button class="btn btn-sm btn-success disableBtn">Disable</button>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>

    <script>
      // window.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function() {
        var fnConstruct = function(element, event, action) {
          console.log(element);
          console.log(event);
          // console.log(action);
          document
            .querySelector(element)
            .addEventListener(event, function() {
              console.log('click');
              console.log(action);
              action;
            });
        };

        var enableControls =
          'document.querySelector("video").removeAttribute("controls");document.querySelector("video").setAttribute("controls", "");';
        fnConstruct(".enableBtn", "click", enableControls);

        var disableControls =
          'document.querySelector("video").removeAttribute("controls");';
        fnConstruct(".disableBtn", "click", disableControls);


      // });
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Note:- Kindly replace the video src attribute to any video you want in your system.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to pass a function instead of a string as `action` and call it in `fnConstruct`:

```
var fnConstruct = function(element, event, action) {
  console.log(element);
  console.log(event);
  document
    .querySelector(element)
    .addEventListener(event, function() {
      console.log('click');
      action();
    });
};

fnConstruct(".enableBtn", "click", function() {
  document.querySelector("video").removeAttribute("controls");
  document.querySelector("video").setAttribute("controls", "");
});

fnConstruct(".disableBtn", "click", function() {
  document.querySelector("video").removeAttribute("controls");
});
```

Comment: Hey, Thanks! It worked like charm. Kudos to you. I wasted almost an hour to figure out the problem. But one more help, please. Could you explain why it was not working before and why it worked with your code?

Comment: You are welcome @Ankit. It did not work before because the code in strings (`enableControls` and `disableControls`) was never evaluated. You could use [eval](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/eval) to evaluate the code in strings (`eval(action)`), but eval usage is generally discouraged due to the security reasons so wrapping the code in functions is a better approach.

Comment: Ok. So the variable that I have sent were treated like String in fnConstruct function. And not as executable code. But when we sent it as a function (as per your approach) it was treated like code. Did I get that right?